# About in app billing questions

Tags: android, ios, in-app-billing

I'm trying to sign up for application billing, and now I can buy an app, but I have doubts that it's killing me and that really keeps me from continuing with this.

1-How can I link a subscription purchase with a user number not my server? For example: the user of a subscription with a google account and receives the premium, but is not linked to your account without my server, but your google purchase, therefore, has a user enter another phone within my application, he Will it have premium premiums, is this normal? that's how it works?

2- How can I ensure that the user who purchases a non-premium premium subscription is also approved for the premiums without iOS?

3 - For a validation of a purchase without google server, I noticed that I need a tokenId, subscriptionId and purchaseId, and this requires an outh token in google to return signature information, such as if it was approved, refused or at what time expires signature.

4-In question number 3, how can I do this? How can I verify that all signed signatures have been approved and expire? I'm a beginner in programming, and as information on what's new, whether as a library, is not on Android, but on a web server

I'm using the analysis server and I'm not sure if it's possible to run server-side applications, or if you want to do that.

**Conclusion, should I link premium benefits to the connected user with the google account and not with the user account in my app?**

Comment: In-App purchases are always linked to google account and not your server.

Comment: This has already clarified some things, thank you, but I will still wait for a few more answers.